# remove line break between linguex a. b. etc sentences

Tags: line-breaking, linguex

I want to generate two trees (using forest) side by side numbered with linguex as a. and b. In other words I want to remove the line break between a. and b. for a single example in linguex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{linguex} 
\begin{document}  

\ex. \a. \begin{forest} baseline
[A [B][C]]
\end{forest}
\b. \begin{forest} baseline
[D [E][F]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I tried using minipage but it only works for different examples `\ex. tree 1 \ex. tree2` not `\ex. \a. tree 1 \b. tree 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `multicol` package. Note that the blank line before `\end{multicols}` is required to end the `ex.` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{linguex} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}  
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ex. \a. \begin{forest} baseline
[A [B][C]]
\end{forest}
\b. \begin{forest} baseline
[D [E][F]]
\end{forest}

\end{multicols}
```

[image: output of code]